# C-Access Members of Struct using index

Tags: c

I have a Structure defined which looks like this

```
struct tindex
{
  char* fcode;
  char* fdesc;
  int fstartidx;
  int fsize;
  char* ftype;
  char* precision;
  char* fcons;
  char* notnull;
  char* ronly;
  char* wdth;
  char* res2;
  char* cel;
  char* flr;
};
```

I want to read the member of structure using index like

```
struct tindex *idx= (struct tindex*)malloc(sizeof(struct tindex));
sscanf(cur,"%s",idx[0]); //Access first member of struct
```

Is this possible by using any tricks?

Comment: No this is not possible by any tricks

Comment: I disagree a tiny bit on that.  The offsets could be stored in an array somewhere and then used to lookup a member, _but_ you still need to know that member's type _and_ it's less efficient _and_ it'll annoy every other C programmer who comes in contact with your code.  A good counter-question is _why do you want to do this_?

Comment: Be advised that theoretically, a C compiler could add padding to promote a better addressing scheme for your struct. The article below recommends you use the `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)` pre-processor directives to selectively avoid padding.

  [1]: https://metricpanda.com/rival-fortress-update-35-avoiding-automatic-structure-padding-in-c

Comment: @armitus: IMNSHO you'll normally do better to avoid tinkering with the packing.

Comment: Do I recall correctly it is OK to access the first member through a pointer to struct (with proper casting)? That would mean that the code as presented is not wrong, apart from the wrong pointer type passed to sscanf (because it's lacking a cast).

Comment: One way to do this is to use C++ and overload `operator[]` for the struct. That exposes an underlying logical issue though that you encounter with any tricky solution in C as well: You have elements of different types (and thus the return types of the index operation are different, and you need different printf formats). You'll need a distinct function *for  every type*, i.e. you would have to know what type an element at a given index is, anyway. In that case you can as well just obtain it by name. There is a reason that indexing is only supported for arrays (with homogeneous elements).

Comment: If all members are of the same type, and only then, you can use a union with an array and with the individual members. Just be careful with alignment.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Yes, C has a rule that a pointer to a struct, suitably converted, points to its first member, and vice-versa. However, `idx[0]` is not a pointer. What should be passed to that `scanf` in that case is `(char **) idx` (convert the pointer to a struct to a pointer to the first element, which is itself a pointer to `char`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right with "not a pointer", but one needs to dereference the double pointer, e.g. say  `sscanf(cur,"%s",*(char **)idx);`. `(char **)idx` is a *pointer* to the first object in the struct which happens to be a `char*`, as you say correctly. But you can't pass *that* to scanf: scanf expects the address of a buffer to read from. We would normally just pass `idx->fcode`, and since `(char **)idx` is `&idx->fcode`, we must dereference it. (That would not be necessary if `fcode`were a true char array.)

Answer (score 2):

The goal you have requested is a Bad Idea, and there is almost certainly a better way of achieving the actual goal that motivated this notion.

That said, one way of implementing this that is less bad than some others is to use an array of offsets as [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy) suggested:

```
struct tindex
{
    char* fcode;
    char* fdesc;
    int fstartidx;
    int fsize;
    char* ftype;
    char* precision;
    char* fcons;
    char* notnull;
    char* ronly;
    char* wdth;
    char* res2;
    char* cel;
    char* flr;
};


#include <stddef.h>


void *LookupField(struct tindex *p, int index)
{
    static const size_t Offsets[] =
    {
        offsetof(struct tindex, fcode),
        offsetof(struct tindex, fdesc),
        offsetof(struct tindex, fstartidx),
        offsetof(struct tindex, fsize),
        offsetof(struct tindex, ftype),
        offsetof(struct tindex, precision),
        offsetof(struct tindex, fcons),
        offsetof(struct tindex, notnull),
        offsetof(struct tindex, ronly),
        offsetof(struct tindex, wdth),
        offsetof(struct tindex, res2),
        offsetof(struct tindex, cel),
        offsetof(struct tindex, flr),
    };

    return (char *) p + Offsets[index];
}


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    struct tindex t;
    printf("%p = %p.\n", (void *) &t.fcode, LookupField(&t, 0));
    printf("%p = %p.\n", (void *) &t.fcons, LookupField(&t, 6));
    printf("%p = %p.\n", (void *) &t.flr, LookupField(&t, 12));
}
```

Note that the address is returned only as a `void *` because there are different types in the structure. You still need some mechanism to handle the different types.

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer arithmetic youre using will increase by the sizeof the stuct, so you would need to know how many bytes you need, and cast it to unsigned char * before trying to index into it.  As the comments mention this is a bad idea, bad practice, not portable from 32/64 bit pointers, horrible to read/etc.  That being said it can be done with a platform specific implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tindex 
{
  char* fcode;
  char* fdesc;
  int fstartidx;
  int fsize;
  char* ftype;
  char* precision;
  char* fcons;
  char* notnull;
  char* ronly;
  char* wdth;
  char* res2;
  char* cel;
  char* flr;
};

int main(void) {
  struct tindex *idx= (struct tindex*)malloc(sizeof(struct tindex));
  idx->fstartidx = 42;

  //a more intereting example, base_address[1] will always increment by 1 byte (for example) when you try to implememtn other members
  unsigned char * base_address = (unsigned char *)idx;
  int * why_do_this = (int *)(base_address + 2*sizeof(char*));
  *why_do_this = 43;

  printf("First some sizes: sizeof struct=%zu \t sizeof char *=%zu\t  2*sizeof(char*)=0x%04x\n", sizeof(struct tindex), sizeof(char*), 2*sizeof(char*));
  printf("Starting address %p, new offset %p, delta 0x%04x should be 2* sizeof char *\n", idx, why_do_this, (int)why_do_this - (int)idx);
  printf("The intfstart index value should be %d which actually is now %d", *why_do_this, idx->fstartidx); //the intfstart index
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested on codechef.com/ide has the following output:

```
First some sizes: sizeof struct=96   sizeof char *=8     2*sizeof(char*)=0x0010
Starting address 0x5573c0327010, new offset 0x5573c0327020, delta 0x0010 should be 2* sizeof char *
The intfstart index value should be 43 which actually is now 43
```

As some of the other comments suggest, if your struct is not packed down to the byte with `#pramga pack` you will have to account for padding.  Use the conventional ways to printf the addresses then make sure you "index variables" point to the same address.

Actually, dont ever do this at all unless your just curious.  Interesting question though so ill give it a thumbs up, even though its useless practically, from a theoretical answer this one was more interesting than some others ive tried to get rep from.

Comment: *platform specific implementation* – What you do is not just platform specific but a sure fired way to shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later (hey, who needs a gun when there is C?). I suggest you read some of Linus rants about gcc and strict aliasing. Yes, it might work but it also might not work, it might stop working with the next compiler version, it might cause you endless pain debugging.

Comment: @Swordfish I literally put this as the answer:

As the comments mention this is a bad idea, bad practice, not portable from 32/64 bit pointers, horrible to read/etc

Comment: @Swordfish Then i ended the answer with: "Actually, dont ever do this".  Can anyone clarify why i got the thumbs down?  I understand its a stupid idea, and made that clear in my answer.  I didnt ask the original question.

Comment: You are right. You shouldn't be punished for writing a stupid answer to a stupid question. I had to edit your answer before I was able to remove my thumbs-down.

Comment: @Swordfish Thank you for reconsidering.  As a note to future readers, the struct name has been changed but the references to the struct in main have not been changed.  If future person tries to copy/paste this sample/crap code it will fail, change the struct references to match the new tag_index name in main, or change the struct name back to tindex.  Really no one should write code like this anyways so im not gonna bother to fix it.

Comment: Changed it back. Didn't realize it wasn't a typedef. You could have edited yourself instead of writing that note, though.